# What changes in client validation when using Kendo DropDownList in an MVC3 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

I have the following form in a view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ModelValue, Model.ModelSelectList, " - ", new {@class = "kendo-skip-dropdown"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ModelValue)
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

I also have the call `$("select").not(".kendo-skip-dropdown").kendoDropDownList();` in my page load code in _Layout.cshtml, to style all my `select` elements as Kendo *DropDownList* widgets.

`ModelValue == null` is true for all tests, and with the `kendo-skip-dropdown` class applied, the dropdown is dead standard, and when I attempt a post without selecting a value, I get the expected "field is required" client-side error. If I remove the `kendo-skip-dropdown` class and let Kendo UI do its work, and attempt a post without selecting a value, I get a "must be a number" client-side error, indicating my `optionLabel` default is now accepted as a value.

The HTML rendered for the dropdown when I use Kendo is:

```
<span tabindex="0" style="" class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header"><span class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default k-state-hover"><span class="k-input">-</span>
    <span class="k-select"><span class="k-icon k-arrow-down">select</span></span></span>
    <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ModelValue must be a number." data-val-required="The ModelValue field is required." id="ModelValue"
        name="ModelValue" style="display: none;" class="input-validation-error">
        <option>-</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
    </select></span>
```

What could be different here, and can anyone tell me how to keep my validation consistent between non-Kendo and Kendo select lists?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use data annotations for the vast majority of my validation. I haven't had to dive too deeply into the differences between the standard validator and Kendo's validator, but I have had to use the [Required] and such attributes.

Have you looked at the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/validator) yet? It might be something along the lines of one rule being applied in a different order for standard versus Kendo types (in Kendo it checks Required first and stops, in standard it checks the numeric value first?)

One way you could insure consistency is to always use the Kendo Validator or you could look at overriding the helpers so that the standard ValidationMessage is consistent between the two.